# configuration error in batch import NEO4J

Tags: java, csv, import, neo4j

I am working on a graphical database tool called "neo4j " by neotechnologies. Here I want to import data into the database from excel.

To do that, I am using a [batch importer](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14493611/batch_importer_20.zip)

Here I have edited my neo4j server properties and I have generated the *relations.csv* and *nodes.csv* that will be imported into the database.

Now, when I try to run the *import.sh* file as per the instructions in readme file, I always get following error:

> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO:
>   os::commit_memory(0x000000074af50000, 2863333376, 0) failed;
>   error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
>
> There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
>   Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 2863333376 bytes for committing reserved memory.
>   An error report file with more information is saved as:
>   /"path"/hs_err_pid16993.log

There is no *batch.properties* file in this package, so I created one for myself and added the code as to increase the buffer size (memory size):

```
use_memory_mapped_buffers=true
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=100M
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=500M
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=1G
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=200M
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=0M
neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys.mapped_memory=15M
neostore.propertystore.db.index.mapped_memory=15M
batch_import.node_index.users=exact
```

Any suggestions would be a great help.

OS version : Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
neo4j version : 2.02

Comment: What distribution of Neo4j are you using? Specifically, the version and the OS.

Comment: How much memory do you have on your machine?

Comment: Check the import.sh which defaults to 4G heap but your JVM fails to allocate 2.3G heap already.

Answer (score 1):

Amend to your `batch.properties`:

```
cache_type=none
```

Also choose an appropriate value for JVM parameter -Xmx. E.g. if you have 8 GB in the machine, and your MMIO config in batch.properties is ~2G, you could set Xmx to e.g. 4G as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

'Cannot allocate memory' means that the Java virtual machine cannot allocate the memory you start it with. How much RAM does your machine have? Open the import.sh file in an text editor and set the -Xms and -Xmx parameter to an appropriate value. (On an 8GB machine I would use "-Xms6G" and "-Xmx6G")